# FCM notification on-click always open in new tab (web-app Polymer)

Tags: firebase, web-applications, polymer, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging in a web-app (with Polymer and a service-worker and using the custom-sw of the SDK).

It is working great (on both desktop and android) but when the user click on the notification it is always opening the `click_action` in a new tab even if a tab of the same origin is opened (but not focused).

click_action = `"https://example.firebaseapp.com/demo/command"`
Url of inactive tab = `"https://example.firebaseapp.com/demo"`

It seems that the `getWindowClient_` method of the FCM SDK is not parsing correctly the URL of active clients and so can't call `focus()` on the inactive tab.

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

That is how it is designed. It caught me off guard at first, but after I thought about it, the new tab/window made sense.

1) the service worker is a separate process from the browser.
2) when a notification displays it is not associated with a browser tab/window.
3) changing the url in an existing window would most likely confuse/irritate the user.

When the user clicks your button the notification assumes no active tab on the origin. So it opens a new window.

Comment: So it is not possible to `focus()` a tab with the same origin as the `click_action` ? The service worker is forced to open a new tab everytime ? What about if the webapp is in standalone mode ? (It is surprising because it seems that the FCM SDK is trying to retrieve a tab of the same origin)

Comment: I have the same problem, and if you try examples from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js all works as expected, after click on push notification user is redirected to already opened tab. I can't get this working in my app.

Comment: I got that working but the URL must be exactly the same, including the hashbang if you have one

Comment: let me know what you mean by hashbang @demsey

Comment: url.com#!example or url.com#example